# How to Talk to Moderator?

Tags: support

In a snafu, [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/127929/files-corrupted-on-system-restore) was moved from SO to ServerFault<sup>*</sup>, where it will be snobbed and ignored as a workstation question. How can I indicate to someone that it should be migrated to Superuser? On ServerFault I barely have rights to leave a comment, much less mark it for close.

<sup>* This is no doubt due to my vague initial question.</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could flag for moderator attention on SF? I *believe* you have enough access for that. I can *possibly* also re-migrate from SO to SU if that would be better. Or you could just ask the question anew on SU and flag (on SF) for someone to kill it.

Comment: Good point, didn't know that, flagged it. Thanks Marc!

Comment: On the other hand, if you can remigrate to SU that would be much better. It's not really appropriate for ServerFault.

Comment: But then it's still on SF, so that leaves the option of it being sent again to SU or just being deleted. @yar

Comment: Yeah, either way is fine, I just need to get it onto SU where it might be answered. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I moved it:

[Non-restored Files Corrupted on System Restore](https://superuser.com/questions/126027/files-corrupted-on-system-restore)

Comment: Thanks Jeff, glad you're not a unicorn.